# ¿Como puedo buscar un nombre guardado en un arreglo de tipo string, escribiendo el nombre (Java)?

Tags: java, array, string

//Hola chicos necesito ayuda con este codigo, tengo un arreglo de tipo string con 10 datos guardados en una variable de nombre nombre, y necesito buscar si un dato se encuentra en esa variable a partir del nombre del dato, si no esta que me diga que no existe y volver a intentarlo y si esta que me lo muestre y me diga en que posicion esta, los dejo con lo poco que llevo de codigo, soy muy nuevo en esto.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ejercicio_arreglos;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author coco_
 */
public class Ejercicio_Arreglos {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bienvenido a casa");
       String[] nombres = new String[10];
       String nombre;
       String opcion;
    
      
      do{
        for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
            
            nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue un nombre");
            nombres[i] = nombre;
          System.out.println("el nombre se ha guardado como" + nombres[1] + "en la posicion" + i);
            
        }
opcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue el nombre que desee ver: " + "tiene que ser un nombre existente");
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y dinos: cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: @alfabravo gracias no se como ser mas especifico, pero mi pregunta es ¿Como hago para que ese programa me permita buscar un dato guardado en mi arreglo a partir del nombre del dato?

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo  que puedes hacer es ir comparando el arreglo con el dato que ingresa el usuario.

```
boolean exist;
String name;
String[] names = new String[10];

name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Add name");
while (!exist) {        
    for(byte i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        if (names[i].equals(name.trim()))
            exist = true;
    }
    if (exist){
        System.out.println("el nombre se ha guardado como" + nombres[i] + "en la posicion" + i);
    } else {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue el nombre que desee ver: " + "tiene que ser un nombre existente");
    }
 }
```

Por cierto el método `name.trim()` se usa para eliminar espacios iniciales y finales por si el usuario le da un espacio demás.

Si estas solo haciendo una prueba puedes utilizar String pero si ya es algo más serio deberías optar por usar StringBuilder, ya que cada vez que le das un nuevo valor a String este crea un nuevo objeto quedando el anterior en memoria.

Pero no te estreses si recién empiezas con Java es normal usar las clases más conocidas, después ya irás averiguando más cosas por ti mismo.

Answer (score 0):

veo que ya estás almacenando los datos desde un Input Dialog. Para lograr buscar sobre el arreglo, puedes usar una búsqueda lineal dentro de un ciclo de validación, de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido a casa");

        String[] nombres = new String[10];

        // Siempre debes usar <arreglo>.length para obtener el largo de un array
        for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
            nombres[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Agregue un nombre");

            System.out.println("El nombre se ha guardado como " + nombres[1] + " en la posicion " + i);
        }

        // usamos una variable para marcar la posicion al salir del ciclo de validación
        int indice = -1;

        // este es el ciclo do-while de validación
        do {
            String opcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("agregue el nombre que desee ver: tiene que ser un nombre existente");

            // acá buscamos linealmente el elemento <opcion> dentro del arreglo <nombres>
            for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
                
                // entonces si el elemento se encuentra, almacenamos el indice actual del ciclo
                if (opcion.equals(nombres[i])) {
                    indice = i;
                    
                    // y luego rompemos el ciclo for. El siguiente paso será comprobar
                    // que el indice no es igual a -1 pero la condicion no se cumple y rompe
                    // también el ciclo do-while
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (indice == -1);
        
        // finalmente mostramos el indice del elemento encontrado
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("El elemento se encuentra en el indice " + indice);
    }
}
```

También puedes escribir un programa usando funciones de streams de java 8, ej:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido a casa");

        String[] nombres = Stream
                .generate(() -> JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Agregue un nombre"))
                .limit(10)
                .toArray(String[]::new);

        int indice;
        do {
            String texto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("agregue el nombre que desee ver: tiene que ser un nombre existente");

            indice = IntStream.range(0, nombres.length)
                    .filter(i -> texto.equals(nombres[i]))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(-1);
        } while (indice == -1);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El elemento se encuentra en el indice " + indice);
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono de maravilla